# Android project don't run in the device when support library is included in the pom.xml

Tags: android, maven, android-support-library

I am having some trouble to run my current android project in my device. the project is built with no erros (with maven), but when I run this error happens:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(12097): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(12097): Process: org.hello, PID: 12097
E/AndroidRuntime(12097): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.hello/org.hello.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.hello.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.hello-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.hello-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime(12097):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2124)
E/AndroidRuntime(12097):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
E/AndroidRuntime(12097):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
E/AndroidRuntime(12097):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
E/AndroidRuntime(12097):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(12097):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(12097):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
E/AndroidRuntime(12097):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(12097):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(12097):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
E/AndroidRuntime(12097):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
E/AndroidRuntime(12097):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(12097): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.hello.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.hello-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.hello-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime(12097):        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime(12097):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
E/AndroidRuntime(12097):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
E/AndroidRuntime(12097):        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1084)
E/AndroidRuntime(12097):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2115)
E/AndroidRuntime(12097):        ... 11 more
W/ActivityManager(  916):   Force finishing activity org.hello/.MainActivity
```

My MainActivity class is that:

```
package org.hello;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab1"), Tab1Fragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab2"), Tab2Fragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Tab3"), Tab3Fragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab4").setIndicator("Tab4"), Tab4Fragment.class, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                openSearch();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                openSettings();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void openSearch() {
      //
    }

    public void openSettings() {
      //
    }
}
```

my pom.xml is that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.hello</groupId>
    <artifactId>basic-tabs</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>

    <properties>
        <!-- use UTF-8 for everything -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <android.sdk.path>/home/kleber/android-sdk-linux/</android.sdk.path>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
           <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
           <version>20.0.0</version>
           <scope>system</scope>
           <systemPath>/home/kleber/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.0-rc.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>19</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <executable>/home/kleber/jdk1.7.0_55/bin/javac</executable>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

the class MainActivity is placed in the correct directory inside my project (same as other projects, which run without problems).

If I remove the dependency `support-v4` (and all  the referenced in my code for class from this library), I have no problem to run this project.

Anyone can see what I am missing here?

ps.: the project with problem is this: https://github.com/klebermo/basic_tab2

Answer (score 2):

I can't remember correctly but I had the same error using that support-v4 library, and I didn't even use Maven. But since you are really desperate for help, here is an idea that I think it fixed my problem. If you have Eclipse (I don't know about other IDEs) go to the build path and go to Order and Export and remove or set Export in the support-v4 library.

Comment: I am not using Eclipse, but Atom for coding and Maven for build/package/deploy. I can't remove the android suport library because some of the libraries I use in the project are available only in this library.

Comment: Maybe try this? Use one of the following <dependency> instead of those shown above. From version 20.0.0 the support-v4 & v13 are packaged as aar instead of jar. Use this: <type>aar</type> in the dependency of the support-v4 https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer

Comment: Here in my system, the library is packaged as jar.

Comment: In that link it is explaining how some libraries were missing from Maven central and how you can use some libraries and also the support-v4. It talks about some difficulties that might arise from using version 20.0.0 onwards. Take a close look. Sorry I can't help more. I know how frustrating configuration problems might be.

Answer (score 1):

clean your project and delete `/gen` and `/bin` folders under your project's directory and then rebuild it!

Comment: I have tried that (the build process generate a target directory instead - i am using maven), and don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried including the jar directly in the project, to see if it makes a difference ?